# Protecting user files after installation with ClickOne

Tags: c#, clickonce

For example .sqlite files, or use custom files.
How can I protect use files after update? ClickOne every update deletes these files. This is very unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You could put any files that need to change separate from the click once files. Probably in the %LocalAppData% folder.

If you have default values you want to keep, you could manage it by creating a copy of the downloaded file in the localAppData, if such a copy do not already exists. If you have a server you could download other files separately if needed.